# How to write the linear operator to transform a Matrix to its lower triangle part

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

$OP$(A matrix $M$ -> its lower triangular part $L$) is a linear transformation. So there must be a linear operator $OP$, which must can be represented as a Matrix $M_{OP}$.

My question is: how to write out the matrix $M_{OP}$.

For instance. $M=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$,$L=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\c & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

$OP(M)=L$ is a linear operator

What is Matrix of $M_{OP}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Rather than using "OP", I'll use $\phi$; using two letters for a symbol is a bit confusing.  Also, I'm assuming that you're working over the real numbers, but the same applies over $\Bbb C$ or arbitrary fields.

---

For a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$, there is a matrix which can unambiguously be referred to as "the matrix of the transformation".  In particular: if $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a linear transformation, then there exists a unique matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ such that $T$ is described by
$$
T(x) = Ax
$$
where "$Ax$" is the usual matrix multiplication.

When you have a linear operator on some other (finite dimensional) vector space, you no longer have a canonical "matrix of the transformation".  However, we can still refer to the matrix of a transformation *with respect to* some choice of basis.  For more information on that, you should pick up a linear algebra textbook and look into the section on "change of basis" or "the matrix of a transformation".

In your particular case: $\phi$ is a map from $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ to $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$.  The most commonly used basis for this space is
$$
\mathcal B = 
\left\{
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
\right\}
$$
Our linear transformation $\phi$ can be written as
$$
\phi\left[
a\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}+
b\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}+
c\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}+
d\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
\right] = 
c\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
As such, the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to our basis $\mathcal B$ (which can be denoted by $[\phi]_{\mathcal B} , [\phi]_{\mathcal B \to \mathcal B}, [\phi]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B}$) can be written as 
$$
[\phi]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0}
$$